# jQuery image upload issue with Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I am facing problem with Internet Explorer while uploading images.

Following is a code jQuery/AJAX post. This code  works fine in other browsers (Mozilla/Chrome) except on IE.

```
<input id="Upload" type="button" value="Upload" />
<input type="file" name="file" id="AdFile" style="display: none" />

$('#Upload').click(function () {
     $('input[id=AdFile]').click();
});

$('#AdFile').change(function () {
     uploadAd($("#AdFile")[0].files[0]);
});

function uploadAd(file) {
var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('File', file);
    formData.append('ParentId', parentId);
    formData.append('FileType', fileType);
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "@Url.Action("UploadAd", "Ad")",
       data: formData,
       contentType: false,
       processData: false,
       success: function (data) {
         if (data.Success) {
           $('#AdList').append("<option value='" + data.Ad.AdId + "'>" + data.Ad.FileName + "</option>");
         }
       }
    }).fail(function (data) {
        //FAIL?
    }).done(function () {
    });
    return false;
 }
```

I guess "FormData" doesn't work with IE. What is the alternative for the same?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the comma processData: false, check it out, it will be work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however removing comma after "processData: false" would show you the error on VS2012 IDE. Also stops executing. Please verify.

Answer (score 0):

See this...

Change this for IE:

```
$('#AdFile').change(function () {
     uploadAd($("#AdFile")[0].files[0]);
})
```

for:

```
$('#AdFile').change(function () {
     uploadAd($(this)[0]);
});
```

And this line

```
url: "@Url.Action("UploadAd", "Ad")",
```

for:

```
url: "@Url.Action(" + UploadAd + ", " + Ad + ")",
```

And see this [jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/dvnjy/4/)

Greetings.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did the changes, still the same.
Also, "jsFiddle Example" works fine on Chrome, however on IE you will not get alert("uploading file...").

Comment: On IE "($("#AdFile")[0].files[0])" and usage of FormData ("var formData = new FormData();" are the issues.

Comment: @user2003820 See the answer again in the function of change event... use this option $('#AdFile:eq(0)')... Greetings.

Comment: Thanks. After doing the suggested changes, I am getting "file = null" in controller method. Even in Chrome.


[HttpPost]
public JsonResult UploadAd(HttpPostedFileBase File, string ParentId, string FileType) { 
...
}

Comment: Also, issue is not with "uploadAd($(this)[0]);" only. It is with FormData as well. This doesn't work on IE. However on Chrome and Mozilla this same piece works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
if(typeof FormData == "undefined"){
var formData = [];
formData.push('File', file);
formData.push('ParentId', parentId);
formData.push('FileType', fileType);
}
else{
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('File', file);
formData.append('ParentId', parentId);
formData.append('FileType', fileType);
}
```

Hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

For ie you need to use a third parameter in the append method when you try to upload a file.

```
formData.append(name, value, filename);
```

IE will change the filename inside the Blob on the fly. To have direct control of the sent filename, the developer should send the filename as the third parameter value, i.e. formData.append(name, value, filename).

Check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append

Furthermore, in some older versions of ie (I believe < ie9), uploading files from a hidden input is not allowed.